# Changing text color on press

Tags: android

The rows of my list have a custom selector.  The background for this selector is color A when not pressed and color B when pressed.  A TextView on the item's layout is colored B for juxtaposition when the list item is not pressed.

However, I would like the text color to change to color A while the row is being pressed, to juxtapose with the new background color.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can style your text with a textColor drawable:

```
<style name="listLabel">
  <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item> 
  <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/list_selector_text</item> 
</style>
```

and drawable/list_selector_text looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/white" /> 
  <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/offwhite" /> 
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/white" /> 
  <item android:color="@color/black" /> 
</selector>
```